# Fade in background that is in the javascript along with video

Tags: javascript, css, dom, background-image, fadein

Currently only the video fades in.
How do I fade in the background that is in the JavaScript along with the video?
What would need to be adjusted in the code for this to work?
How it works is, clicking on the play image fades in the background along with the video.

https://jsfiddle.net/7syrbnht/

**CSS:**

```
.hide {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
}

.container:not(.hide){
   opacity:0;
   animation: fade 5s ease 0s forwards;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
```

**javascript:**

```
 (function iife() {
   "use strict";

   function show(el) {
     el.classList.remove("hide");
   }

   function coverClickHandler(evt) {
     const cover = evt.currentTarget;
     const thewrap = cover.parentElement.querySelector(".container");
     show(thewrap);
     document.body.style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(teal 5px, #0000 5px), linear-gradient(90deg, teal 5px, #0000 5px), linear-gradient(black 10px, #0000 10px 160px, black 160px), linear-gradient(90deg, black 10px, #0000 10px 160px, black 160px), linear-gradient(orange 15px, #0000 15px 155px, orange 155px), linear-gradient(90deg, orange 15px, #0000 15px 155px, orange 155px), linear-gradient(black 20px, #0000 20px 150px, black 150px), linear-gradient(90deg, black 20px, #0000 20px 150px, black 150px), linear-gradient(teal 25px, #0000 25px 145px, teal 145px), linear-gradient(90deg, teal 25px, #0000 25px 145px, teal 145px), linear-gradient(black 30px, #0000 30px 140px, black 140px), linear-gradient(90deg, black 30px, #0000 30px 140px, black 140px), linear-gradient(orange 35px, #0000 35px 135px, orange 135px), linear-gradient(90deg, orange 35px, #0000 35px 135px, orange 135px), linear-gradient(black 40px, #0000 40px 130px, black 130px), linear-gradient(90deg, black 40px, #0000 40px 130px, black 130px), linear-gradient(teal 45px, #0000 45px 125px, teal 125px), linear-gradient(90deg, teal 45px, #0000 45px 125px, teal 125px), linear-gradient(black 50px, #0000 50px 120px, black 120px), linear-gradient(90deg, black 50px, #0000 50px 120px, black 120px), linear-gradient(orange 55px, #0000 55px 115px, orange 115px), linear-gradient(90deg, orange 55px, #0000 55px 115px, orange 115px), linear-gradient(black 60px, #0000 60px 110px, black 110px), linear-gradient(90deg, black 60px, #0000 60px 110px, black 110px), linear-gradient(teal 65px, #0000 65px 105px, teal 105px), linear-gradient(90deg, teal 65px, #0000 65px 105px, teal 105px), linear-gradient(black 70px, #0000 70px 100px, black 100px), linear-gradient(90deg, black 70px, #0000 70px 100px, black 100px), linear-gradient(orange 75px, #0000 75px 95px, orange 95px), linear-gradient(90deg, orange 75px, #0000 75px 95px, orange 95px), linear-gradient(black 80px, #0000 80px 90px, black 90px), linear-gradient(90deg, black 80px, #0000 80px 90px, black 90px), linear-gradient(teal, teal)";
     document.body.style.backgroundSize = "165px 165px";
     videoPlayer.play();
   }

   const cover = document.querySelector(".play");
   cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
 }());
```

Comment: `function iife()` 

Comment: Try reproducing a simple case.  There's a lot of stuff in there that isn't related to the problem and frankly I can't be bothered to sort through it all.  I've found trying to create a base case myself often helps me find the problem.